# Transaction affects time of computation?

Tags: python, django, performance, concurrency, transactions

Consider:

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    job = Job.objects.select_for_update().get(id=job_id)
    texts = pickle.loads(job.job_body)
    timer = Timer()
    print("Computing embedding for:", texts, flush=True)
    job.started = ms_now()
    result = get_embeddings_raw(texts) # no database communication.
    job.finished = ms_now()
    print("Done computing embedding for:", texts, timer.stop(), flush=True)
    job.result = pickle.dumps(result)
    job.save()
```

The computation within the transaction, performed by `get_embeddings_raw`, does not communicate with the database. Nonetheless, when I do not use concurrency, this computation takes ~70ms, but when there are up to ten simultaneous workers, it takes ~4,000ms. Can transaction cause this slowing down in any way?

Comment: you are communicating with the database inside the `transaction` block - you `get` a row and then later `save` it

Comment: what are you using for concurrency? `get_embeddings_raw` is presumably doing CPU work which will block concurrent work in the same Python process (and same for `pickle.loads/dumps`)

Comment: @Anentropic I don't understand. What does this have to do with the time taken by `get_embeddings_raw`?

Comment: If your concurrency is via threads or async in a single process then Python's GIL will prevent other requests from progressing while `get_embeddings_raw` does CPU work. Another question would be: are your concurrent requests accessing different rows (different `job_id`)?

Comment: @Anentropic The point of the question is why `get_embeddings_raw` becomes slow. Please look what time is measured in the code.

Comment: There is not enough detail in the question to answer it, I tried to ask for more relevant details in the comments. The title of the question is "transaction affects time of computation?" but you said yourself that `get_embeddings_raw` does not touch the db so that theory makes no sense. Clearly the problem is somehow related to concurrency. Do you have a single Python process? And it's Django, are you running as WSGI app or ASGI app? Which web server?